# Finding Out Which nth-child an Element Is

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am editing the CSS of a static framework for an e-commerce store. I can't edit a lot of it but I've been using nth-child to target certain elements in the CSS. The problem is that a lot of the dynamically generated divs, tables and spans don't have class or ID selectors. The framework is built on tables so there's a lot of CSS selectors like this:

```
.sample_CSS_class table:nth-child(5) table
```

This is where a table that's contained within the fifth table under the div with the class "sample_CSS_class" is targeted. This can take a lot of time though. I have to go into the Google Chrome Inspector (or Firebug) and expand the source code and then count down from there. With so much code, I can make mistakes and it also just takes a while.

I was wondering if anyone knows an efficient way to find out the nth-child number of an element with something like Firebug or Google Chrome Inspector (or any other tool that's out there). Thanks!

Comment: This tester could be useful http://lea.verou.me/demos/nth.html

Comment: do you have the app running somewhere? Its too theoretical.

Comment: There are various xpath helper tools out there.  When you view an elements xpath, the very last number in brackets is the child order number of that element.  You can do this without any extensions in Chrome Inspectory with Right Click -> Copy XPath on the target element, but then you have to paste it somewhere and that could be a bit tedious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Chrome, you can use the *Copy XPath* context menu entry to sort of do it:

[image: XPath stuff]

It'll give you an XPath selector that looks like this:

```
//*[@id="sidebar"]/div[4]/div/div[13]
```

`div[13]` is like `div:nth-child(13)`. It'd be really nice if Chrome had a *Copy CSS* option, but for some reason it doesn't. Maybe someone will make an extension.